# If there exists a primitive element of a finite extension a field, there are finite number of nested fields. Where is "primitiveness" used?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This is known as **Primitive Element Theorem**, stated for reference (Lang's Algebra; V.4. Theorem 4.6, page 243):

Let $E$ be a finite extension of a field $k$. There exists $\alpha\in E$ such that $E=k(\alpha)$ iff there are finite number of fields $k\subset F\subset E$.

Where is the fact that $E=k(\alpha)$ used in $\Rightarrow$ of proof? In other words, where will the proof fail if this isn't the case? I just cannot see it.

Ignoring this assumption, take arbitrary $\alpha \in E$ and nested field $F$. There always exists irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$: $g_F(X)$ and $g_F | Irr(\alpha, k, X)$. There are always only finite number of these polynomials (since we have unique factorization in $E^a[X]$), so we *always* have a mapping:
$$F\rightarrow g_F$$

We can always generate subfield $F_0$ by coefficients of $g_F$ and this $\alpha$ is irreducible over $F_0$ and so $F=F_0$, whence mapping is injective.

Comment: Well it might be true in more general circumstances, but it is certainly true if there is a primitive element. The point is to show that two things are equivalent, not to prove the best possible implication each way.

Comment: @FabioLucchini I thought that if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$, then $\alpha$ is algebraic over *any* field extension, so can you please explain why cannot we consider it otherwise?

Mark Bennet yes I know, but I still do not see where we use the primitive element assumption.

Comment: Your mapping associating an intermediate field $F$ to the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ need not be injective if $\alpha$ doesn't generate $E$; any two subfields $F$ and $F'$ of $E$ containing $\alpha$ will both be mapped to minimal polynomial $x - \alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap is in the proof of $F_0=F$.
Clearly $F_0\subseteq F$.
To prove the opposite inclusion, namely $F\subseteq F_0$ we have
$$[F_0(\alpha):F_0]\leq\deg(g_F)=[F(\alpha):F]$$
If $E=k(\alpha)$, then $F_0(\alpha)=E=F(\alpha)$, hence we can conclude $F=F_0$.